# How to conditionally select NoSQL database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an app connected with MongoDB database. App is parsing external data and is putting this data to a database. Now I have different 3 sources of products data (let's say `vegetables`, `fruits` and `beverages`) and I want to put product data to separate databases.

My `app.js` is parsing data this way:

```
const Product = require('./models/product');
...
let product = await Product.findOneAndUpdate({ SKU }, $set: data);
...
```

I would like to define somewhere on the app.js level which database will be chosen i.e. based on the script arguments.

For now my `model.js` looks like this now:

```
const mongoose = require('../db/mongodb');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    SKU: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        ES: { type: String },
        FR: { type: String },
        EN: { type: String },
        DE: { type: String },
        IT: { type: String },
    },
    description: {
        ES: { type: String },
        FR: { type: String },
        EN: { type: String },
        DE: { type: String },
        IT: { type: String },
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

and my `mongodb.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let mongoDB = 'mongodb+srv://user:pass@url/database1';


mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

module.exports = mongoose;
```

The link to the database is hardcoded inside `require` file `mongodb.js`. What would be the best option to conditionally select `mongoDB` link in `app.js`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier and more correct to just create [multiple connections](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html), wouldn't it?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb+srv://user:pass@url/database1');
const conn2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb+srv://user:pass@url/database2');
```